# Component coming back as undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting

> ./src/App.js Line 37:  'Output' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

but I cannot see my mistake. I have imported Output properly from what I can see, I have also Exported properly, I dont see any errors in the jsx syntax, or the rest of the syntax in general.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Ouput from './Components/Output';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      paras: 4,
      html: true,
      text: ""
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getSampleText();
  }

  getSampleText() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://hipsterjesus.com/api?paras=" +
          this.state.paras +
          "&html=" +
          this.state.html)
      .then(response => {

        this.setState({ text: response.data.text }, function() {
          console.log(this.state);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {console.log(error);
  });
}
      render() {
    return ( <div className="App">
      <Output value={this.state.text} />
    </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Output.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Output extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: props.value

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (<div className="output">
            {this.props.value}
           </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Output
```

Comment: you missing a `t` in `import Ouput from ...` should be `Output`

Comment: Thanks So Much , i knew it was something dumb like that, appreciate it!